# Loading a Java .properties file, getting java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, configuration, spring-mvc, properties

I'm new to loading a custom .properties file and am doing so from within my Spring MVC app.

I have a properties file at: `com.company.wtwebapp.properties.wtwebapp.properties`

I have tried as below as well as a variety of combinations (leaving out the src.main.java, using "/" instead of ".") but nothing works.

```
          ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle
          ("src.main.java.com.company.wtwebapp.properties.wtwebapp.properties");
```

On my classpath file I have:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/java/com/company/wtwebapp/properties/wtwebapp.properties"/>
```

I always get the error:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name src.main.java.com.company.wtwebapp.properties.wtwebapp.properties, locale en_US
```

I would appreciate any advice on the proper way / better way to accomplish the loading of the properties file. I have been doing a lot of searches but they are just leading to more confusion as from what I can tell what I am doing should be working (but obviously something is wrong). Thanks

Comment: I find disturbing that your package begins with "src". May it be a reference to the source folder?

Comment: I'm just going by the class path, I normally wouldn't try it that way, as I said I tried without that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the javadoc:

> getBundle attempts to locate a
>   property resource file. It generates a
>   path name from the candidate bundle
>   name by replacing all "." characters
>   with "/" and appending the string
>   ".properties".

You are supposed to provide the basename only; remove the `.properties` suffix.  Also if the bundle is in the same directory as the class, remove all the path information.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your resource bundle like this:

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.company.wtwebapp.properties.wtwebapp");
```

And modify your classpath entry like so:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/java"/>
```